# How do I counter Sonic?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

On Super Smash Bros 4 (SSB4), I am a decent player. Winning some matches, and losing others. But, I seem to lose most of matches against a Sonic, unless the player is all around bad. I find it difficult to hit them while they spam their Side + B and their basic B. Is there anyway to counter it effectively?

I mainly play as Ganon, Falco, Captain Falcon, Ike, Ness, and Little Mac.

Comment: Down b with marth counters sonic

Comment: @Cilan it took me this long to realize that you typed out a pun and I am sorry for not noticing until now.

Comment: it’s cool. u r a ssb4 player after all /s

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sonic in SSB4 is quite a difficult match-up due to his movement versatility and options. The best advice I can give you is to **read your opponent**. Regardless of how good your opponent may be, they will most likely exhibit some habits which you can exploit. It's more about outsmarting the player versus finding a formula that will just grant you the "win" every time. However, there are some inherently bad match-ups in the game that are genuinely very difficult since your character has severe handicaps (e.g., Little Mac's recovery against any fast projectile characters).

I suppose some general advice for playing against Sonic:

1. His B move is the homing attack. If you time it right, you can side-roll (L trigger plus a direction) away just as the move is released. It will put Sonic in some idle (after the bounce) for you to capitalize on (e.g., you can use Ganon's Side-B to try set up for a mix-up game).
2. Don't try to play all-out aggressive against Sonic. A good player is a patient player that knows when to go in and when to stay back. If you play a defensive game, it will give you some time to decipher your opponent's playstyle and determine which options work best to counter. I play a Ganon secondary and find his neutral-A on the ground to be an effective tool against Sonic in close quarters, but you can't spam it; you need to time it when they're rushing in (though it isn't as effective in SSB4 as it was in Project M or Melee).
3. Go for the reads. Technical skill/knowledge and intuition are two components to any fighting game player. If you merely learn tech, you become a mechanical and predictable player. Relying solely on intuition takes you a lot further as you play a more adaptive style that you mold to fit your opponent, but can fall short if you don't know how to take advantage of a situation (i.e., going for non-optimal options). Both tech and reads need to complement each other.

Comment: Are there any common tactics for dealing with his Side Special?

Comment: Sonic's side-B is probably one of the most annoying to deal with. Your best bet is to try evade the move either by spot-dodging (holding trigger plus down on the analogue stick) or jump over it. However, if try not to overuse one option too much as:

1. Sonic can jump out of it and do any move besides his second jump,
2. Sonic can shield-cancel the Side-B before it is fully charged, thereby baiting you into dodging too early and the opponent can punish it.

Comment: @ShadowZ - Having said that, some characters have some unique options (e.g., projectile characters can interrupt the side-B). I would recommend getting a friend to pick Sonic and both of you jump into Training mode to experiment. You may discover some innovative ways to deal with Sonic's moveset. Alternatively, you should also try watch some pro matches on Youtube (6WX is a good Sonic player) and try see how other players acclimatize to Sonic.

Comment: @ShadowZ - But the best thing you can do is learn by experience. If you think you have a new idea, don't be afraid to try it in a match against a Sonic player. Unless you're playing for a huge cash prize or a sponsored player, there's no harm in trial-and-error in friendlies or local tournaments. I host a bi-weekly in my region and I always encourage the players to diversify their play.

Comment: @ShadowZ. Sonic's Spin Dash (side-B) is fairly slow at first, has low priority, and makes Sonic an easy and predictable target. You should be able to counter it with any melee attack that activates quickly, or with a counter, such as Ike's down-B or Little Mac's down-B. Falco's laser (neutral-B) and Ness's PK Fire (side-B) should also both have enough stopping power to interrupt the attack.

Comment: Brian is absolutely right, your main characters have a counter built into them. Sonic's side special is very easy to spot coming. Ike and LM both have direct ways of dealing easy damage with their counters. Falco has an auto-stun with a simple neutral special. Ganon and Falcon both can Down Special and their attack is stronger and will take priority over Sonic's weaker Side Special. Remember, Sonic is fast, but his attacks are weak and Sonic has an inability to stop an attack once committed.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about beating Sonic is you have to play smarter; be patient. Don't be overly aggressive and don't overexert for little things such as a jab or grab. The only way to beat Sonic is to capitalize on his end lag and don't let him capitalize on yours.

Answer (score 1):

This probably won't help because you don't main him, but wario counters sonic a lot. Spin dash - chomp, homing attack - chomp,tries to run fast and quickly hit you- chomp. Chomp kills sonic.

Answer (score 1):

My brother is the most annoying sonic player I know, but I have found some tricks that may help you get the upper hand. Some sonic players will use their up B to bet out is sticky situations. Try to get where they land and it is easy to land a grab when they hit the ground. Just be careful because sonic can still attack while in free fall. I would recommend shielding until they hit the ground and then go for a grab. Shielding can also cause a spin dash to be useless, but it is hard to punish after that. Some projectiles are effective at stopping the spin dash as well.

Answer (score 0):

I main Sonic myself, I say the best counters that I have experienced, is Cloud, ZSS, Lucas and Ness, Diddy Kong (Some say its a neutral) his banana can really mess them up, Fast projectile users (Don't use Fox stick with falco) if your using heavy characters, then I recommend little mac because their speed is almost similar, but his recovery can really mess you up. Though I highly recommend that you use his n-B(super armor) That can stop them for a while. Since you use falco, I say you stay back when the user fails to use their spin dash correctly, and shoot them to slow them down, and go really aggressive when said user is recovery, its straight up, and only deals damage below them, so that a perfect time to spike them down, Ike is also a good counter, when they are about to do a up air gimp, counter on their 3rd up air that will you give you enough time to do it. Really that all I recommend.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: Learn to play a stronger [Neutral Game](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Neutral_game), practice counters to specific situations/moves and watch professional players.**

This is a good question and still a real problem for many players. The other answers here hit on the main point: you need a strong [Neutral Game](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Neutral_game). Sonic is fast enough to punish just about anything, even from across the stage. This means if you go throwing out moves, you'll be punished.

So like the other answers mention, instead of trying to rush the Sonic--which probably won't end well with his speed--play things a little slower.

Watch them closely. After they hit you with Side-B (Side Special) regardless of whether they hit you or shield, do they always jump and Neutral-Air? Jump and Forward-Air? If so, then after they hit your shield, you have a jump to Up-Air punish or maybe even more depending on your character.

When playing a Sonic I prefer to use Mewtwo or other characters with a fast Down-Tilt like Roy/Marth/Lucina. When the Sonic comes in with the Side-Special, Mewtwo and friends' Down-Tilt's are fast enough that it's easy to time to knock the Sonic out of it. And then from there Mewtwo has a free Neutral-Air/Forward-Air/any other follow up to D-Tilt.

Outside of bettering your Neutral Game and practicing specific punishes for Sonic's Side-Special, I'd strongly suggest watching professional level competitive play. You can find a list of professional players for each character [here](https://ssbworld.com/characters/) ([here](https://ssbworld.com/characters/mewtwo/top)'s an example of the Mewtwo page). Then from there, you can search YouTube to see how they handle the Sonic matchup (continuing the Mewtwo example, [this](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=wadi+vs+sonic&page=&utm_source=opensearch) is what such a search would look like).

Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

Sonic is pretty squishy.

Try grabbing him, then throwing him up to make him in the air then finish him off with some aerials. Not everyone's style of play but I sure use it.